# What do the sign and the value of a slope tell us regarding the nature of the straight line?

Tags: slope

What could be the minimum and maximum possible value for a slope of a straight line?

Is it -1   to  +1 ?

What do the sign and the value tell us regarding the nature of the straight line?

Comment: What is the slope of the line $y = 2x + 3$?  Is that slope between -1 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

Slopes can be more than one and less than negative one.

A slope determines how steep a line is and the sign indicates if it's going "uphill" or "downhill".

The lowest *absolute* slope (the absolute value of a slope) is $0$ which means the line is perfectly horizontal.  A very small slope, so $\frac 1{10}$ means it's slightly up hill. (And a slope of $-\frac 1{10}$ means it's slightly downhill.)

A slope of $1$ means it rises just as fast as it goes forward.  The slope is at a $45^{\circ}$ angle.  (And a slope of $-1$ means it sinks just as fast as it goes forward).  This is not a limit.  You can have lines that are steeper.

A slope of more than $1$ means it raises faster than it goes forward.  A huge slope such ans $1000$ would mean if you go forward $1$ foot you will go up $1000$ feet.  (Same for negatives but downhill.)

Now there *is* a problem.  Do you see what it is?

What if the line is perfectly vertical?  Then we say the slope is infinite.  The equation of such a line can not be written as $y = mx + b$. It must be written as $x = c$.  ($y$ can be any point and $x$ will always be $c$.)

For a vertical line with infinite slope, it doesn't make sense to talk of negative or positive or going "uphill" or "downhill".  It's simple a straight drop with *no* forward or backward motion.

====

Also.  You can write a line if $y=mx +b$ form for *any* $m$ or $b$.  As $m$ can be *any* number the slope can have *any* value and if you think of it that way, of course it isn't limited to being between $-1$ and $1$.

The line $y=7x -3$ *will* be a line that has a steepness that for every one unit you go forward, you will go up $7$ units.  That's a slope of $7$.

Comment: If a line passes through 1st and 3rd quadrant, is it rising or declining?

Comment: Well, which quadrant is higher?  And which quadrant is to the left or the right.  You *do* understand what rising and declining mean don't you?  I mean is you walk up a staircase you are rising an if you walk down a staircase you are declining  *Look* at the line.  Is it going up (from left to right) or is it going down (from left to right)?  This isn't any trick.